# "let me go into the building" or "let me into the building"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm trying to describe a situation where I tried to going into a building but the police officers didn't let me. Which one of the sentences would be correct in this case:

> ... they didn't even let me into the building

> ... they didn't even let me go into the building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these expressions are correct and the mean the same.

"Let me in" is idiomatic meaning "let me enter" or "Let me go in".

"Let me" can be used with a verb "Let me play", or a preposition/adverb: "Let me through" "Let me under the blanket".

Answer (score 1):

The most common idiomatic phrade is "Let me in" or the more formal one "Let me come in". Besides this you can use the phrase "Let me inside".

Often when guards stand in your way and don't let you pass you can here "Let me through".